# How to reduce time complexity in this problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I have been recently asked this question in an interview and I am wondering how to answer this.

> You have a 2D matrix of binary digits in any random order
>   `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`
>   `1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0`
>   `1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1`
>   `1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0`
>   `1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1`
>   `1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0`
>
> And you need to find the occurance of this pattern
>   `1`
>   `11`

So, looking at the above matrix it is evident that the answer is **6**.
And I solved it like this

```
unsigned int Findpairs(const std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>>& A) {
    unsigned int count = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (A.size()-1); i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < (A[i].size()-1); j++){
            if(A[i][j]==1 && A[i+1][j]==1 && A[i+1][j+1]==1){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return (count);
}
```

The next question was to get a better time complexity.
I could not answer **the exact solution**.

Can someone help me with this? I just want to know this for my own curiosity.

Comment: To start, ask yourself two questions.   First, what is the time complexity of yo9ur algorithm?   Second, what drives that?    If you can't answer those questions, you're not in a position to know if time complexity can be improved, let alone how.

Comment: Well for this solution, I have the T-complexity as `O(n^2)` The 2 for loops are going to be executed always. I simply could not find a better solution still. is there any

Comment: I think the intent of the interviewer would to see your thinking process. This question is very similar to finding a substring (length m) in a given string (length n), the naive algorithm of which has a complexity of `O(n*m)`. In this case, the search space is 2-d and the complexity is `O(n^2 * m)` where `m` is the length of the pattern to be searched (3 in your case). Perhaps, the interviewer wanted you to think along similar lines as KMP algorithm (and similar O(n) substring search algorithms) in 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small optimization which is dependent on the input pattern.

```
unsigned int Findpairs(const std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>>& A) {
    unsigned int count = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (A.size() - 1); i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < (A[i].size() - 1); j++) {
            if (A[i + 1][j + 1] == 1) {
                if (A[i + 1][j] == 1 && A[i][j] == 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else {
                j++; //skip a column because our bottom right saw 0
            }
        }
    }

    return (count);
}
```

Comment: nice idea, additional slight imporovements could be 'unit8_t' for the matrix entries and checking '!= 0' instead of '== 1'

Comment: Hey that's a nice idea, I am wondering if it is different from checking `A[i][j] == 1` first followed by `A[i + 1][j] == 1 && A[i + 1][j + 1] == 1`. I think not!!!

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of your operation could be described as O(n) where n is the number of points in your array. Your operation is equivalent to searching for something in an unsorted array. There are ways you may make your algorithm more efficient but you can not perform this type of search in less than linear time, O(n).

For some problems, you can improve the time complexity by first sorting or collecting additional information about the problem. In the case of this problem, you can prove that your solution is linearly related to the size of the array. With a random array, each of the 3 elements has a 50% chance of occurring. For each n, the odds of the pattern occuring is 0.5^3 = 1/8. That means you will count about 1/8*n occurrences of the pattern. **Counting the pattern alone takes O(n) time.**

If your goal was to **Estimate** the number of occurrences in a random array, you can give an estimate in O(1) time. This pattern *should* occur about 1/8*(j-1)*(i-1) times in a random array.

Answer (score 0):

As for the concrete problem, your solution is appropriate.

There are 2 alternative methods that would be beneficial in case of you want to find other patterns in the same matrix or in case of very big matrices and bigger patterns:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

both require some preprocessing of the original matrix, but will then provide faster checks for pattern templates. Youll find implemetations for both in the OpenCV image processing library.